# Regarding Data back up

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (32 bit) OS on Windows 10 (64 bit) OS using Bootable pendrive on my Lenevo laptop. I chose this option **"Erase Windows 10 and install  Ubuntu"** so it has been lead to  erase my perent Windows 10 OS as well as all data of hard disk and installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (32 bit) OS. I updated it from software update and get new update version 18.04.6 version.

So my problem is that how to get my back up data of Windows 10 OS?
Does it possible to get back up data of windows OS using my current OS (Ubuntu 18.04.6 32 bit)?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I regret not by conventional means or by the use of the OS you just installed; a local data recovery service may be able to assist, but please shut that PC down and do nothing else which may write any more data to that drive.